# How to prevent my friends seeing my friend's posts, if he/she posts to 'Friends of friends' or to Public all the time?

Tags: facebook, privacy

I don't want my friends to see my friend's posts, as some of them post to 'Friends of friends' and to 'Public', every single time, which is quite annoying and rude.

Comment: Please consider registering your account. This will mean that you will retain ownership of the question and be able to comment on the answers.

Answer (score 2):

So there are people who you are currently Facebook-friends with who do something that you don't like because it impacts on other people.

In real-life, you would most probably stop being friends with them, because you don't like the consequences of their actions.  So one effective option would be to simply un-friend them.

And I doubt that Facebook provides other options - because why should you have the right to determine what other people can say to your friends?    You do have the right to not invite them both to the same party - but you cannot stop them meeting at the mall, or having other friends in common.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't want to unfriend them,'cause they're still my friends... but the way they post is not right. It's ok if you want to post sth to everyone sometimes, in some occasions, but doing it most of the times for your own promotion or sth... that's not right, 'cause you don't know the people...
As to me, facebook should ban posting to 'Friends of friends' and public. For example, would you stop someone on the street you never seen before (especially if you don't particulary like him/her :) and start talking about sth? Of course, you wouldn't... 1 of a 100 probably... same w

Answer (score 1):

Just avoid liking or commenting on those posts that are posted to Friends of Friends or Public.  If you don't like or comment on them, your other friends will not see those posts unless they see them for other reasons (e.g. they are friends with the poster or another commenter, or they explicitly visit the person's timeline).

Answer (score 0):

There are settings in Facebook that allow you to restrict individual Friends from posting to your wall or liking or commenting on your posts.

http://xnotion.hubpages.com/hub/How-to-Stop-Certain-Friends-From-Commenting-on-Your-Facebook-Posts

They will still see your posts, but cannot get involved in them.  That way, they will still be "Friends" on FB, but restricted from glomming onto your stuff.